# Xcode issue with linking?

Tags: swift, xcode9

having problem with xcode when i try to run the project

created two pods for my project & open xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhrLZ.png

Comment: Edit your question to show the output (click on the error, it should take you there)

Answer (score 0):

Clean project and Re-build. And then run again.

Comment: i did that cleaned it and rebuilded it & still come with same error

Comment: Reinstall your two cocoapods and check in that some file is not missing in your project. If file is missing then Copy from directory again in finder.